# Exploding Multiple Hashtags

Tags: php, hashtag

I'm currently developing a lightweight internal messaging script for a local group, which utilises a custom made BBCode style parser, to translate forum style tags such as [b] into its HTML equivalent.

I've also been including a Twitter like hashtag feature, so people can tag and track discussions within the messaging system, which works well, until the user enters more than one hashtag into the text.

Typically the user would enter their text into the submission form as such.

```
Lorum Ipsum  dolor sit amet, #consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Using SQL, the discussion tracker loads the last 20 messages and loops through them, each time calling the TrackDiscussion($i); function. The $i parameter is where the text/submission is fed into to check for hashtags.

```
function TrackDiscussion($i,$str=1) {
    $keywords="";
    preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$i,$matches);
    $i = 0;
    if($str){
        foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
            $count=count($matches[1]);
            $keywords .= "$match";
            $i++;
            if ($count>$i) $keywords .= ", ";
       }
    }
    else{
        foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
            $keyword[]=$match;
        }
        $keywords=$keyword;
    }
    return $keywords;
}
```

This all works fine, until it finds more than one hashtag in the text, and instead of outputting:

```
<a href="http://example.com/tag/hashtag1">#hashtag1</a>, <a href="http://example.com/tag/hashtag2">#hashtag2</a>
```

It outputs:

```
<a href="http://example.com/tag/hashtag1,hashtag2">#hashtag1, #hashtag2</a>
```

I apologise the the messy code, but would I be right in surmising that I would need split the keywords apart, most likely by the explode function?

If anyone could give me a pointer as to where I would put that, I'd be more than grateful, I've been going over it time and time again and I can't seem to find my error.

Thanks

Comment: The code which actually generates the links is probably the one that's the problem.

Comment: Tour hashtag are stored as string in $keywords, you are concatenating strings. Don't return a string from trackDiscussion(), return an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function TrackDiscussion( $input ) {
    return preg_replace( "~\#(\w+)~i", '<a href="http://example.com/tag/$1">#$1</a>', $input );
}

echo TrackDiscussion( 'Lorum #Ipsum  dolor sit amet, #consectetur adipiscing #elit.' );
```

Or only contain hashtag links?

```
function TrackDiscussion2( $input ) {
    preg_match_all( "~\#(\w+)~i", $input, $matches );
    $return = array();
    foreach( $matches[1] as $match ) {
        $return[] .= '<a href="http://example.com/tag/'.$match.'">#'.$match.'</a>';
    }
    return implode( ', ', $return );
}

echo TrackDiscussion2( 'Lorum #Ipsum  dolor sit amet, #consectetur adipiscing #elit.' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working perfectly now. I don't know why simple answer elude me sometimes. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have broken the logic out into separate functions to make things as simple as possible.
Is this what you are after?

```
$last20Messages = array(
    'This is just some random stuff. #random #stuff',
    'And some more. #some #more',
);
echo getTagLinksForMessages($last20Messages);
```

Outputs:

```
<a href='/tag/random'>#random</a>
<a href='/tag/stuff'>#stuff</a>
<a href='/tag/some'>#some</a>
<a href='/tag/more'>#more</a>
```

And the function definitions:

```
/**
 * @param string $message
 * @return array
 */
function getTagsFromMessage($message)
{
    preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $message, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

/**
 * @param array|string[] $messages
 * @return array
 */
function getTagsFromMessages(array $messages)
{
    $tags = [];
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $messageTags = getTagsFromMessage($message);
        $tags = array_merge($tags, $messageTags);
    }
    $tags = array_unique($tags);

    // You can then sort the tags here. E.g. alphabetical order.
    return $tags;
}

/**
 * @param array $tags
 * @return string
 */
function getTagLinksString(array $tags)
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $result .= "<a href='/tag/{$tag}'>#{$tag}</a>";
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param array $messages
 * @return string
 */
function getTagLinksForMessages(array $messages)
{
    $tags = getTagsFromMessages($messages);
    return getTagLinksString($tags);
}
```

Comment: Both yours and Ron van der Heijden's answer are brilliant. Depending on how the group want it to act in the final version, Ron's is useful for highlighting the hashtags in the text and yours is useful for if a small list of tags is needed without the extra text around it. (While Ron's is the accepted answer, I will upvote yours as well)